# Software to facilitate classification of data by human user

Tags: data-analysis, data, classification

I'm looking for some software that makes it easy for a non-technical person to go through a spreadsheet and sort the rows into categories. The software would make it easy for people to construct rules, along the lines of: "rows containing the word 'apple' should be sorted into the 'fruit' category". Does something like this already exist? Obviously spreadsheet software can do this, but this requires some technical knowledge. Open-source software would be best.

Comment: you need a semantic classifier